# Multiple Upload Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, upload

I'm beginning with Symfony and I'm stuck with multiple upload.

I can upload just one file and I try to modify this code for multiple upload.

Here's my error :

```
Expected argument of type "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile", "array" given
```

Here's my code :

**ImageArticleType:**

```
$builder
        ->add('file', 'file', array('label' => 'Choisir mes images', 'multiple'=> true))
    ;
```

And my Entity **ImageArticle.php**

```
<?php

namespace AD\PlatformBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * ImageArticle
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class ImageArticle
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="url", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $url;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="alt", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $alt;

    /**
     * @var File
     *  
     * @Assert\File(
     *     maxSize = "1M",
     *     mimeTypes = {
     *          "image/jpeg", 
     *          "image/gif", 
     *          "image/png", 
     *          },
     *     maxSizeMessage = "La taille maximum du fichier doit etre inférieur ou égale à 1MB. Pour reduire sa taille vous pouvez utiliser le site : compressjpeg.com",
     *     mimeTypesMessage = "Seulement les fichiers .jpeg / .gif /.png sont acceptés"
     * )
     */
    private $file;

    private $tempFileName;

    public function getFile()
    {   
        return $this->file;
    }

    public function setFile(UploadedFile $file)
    {

        $this->file = $file;

        if (null !== $this->url)
        {
            $this->tempFileName = $this->url;
            $this->url=null;
            $this->alt=null;
        }
    }
    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set url
     *
     * @param string $url
     *
     * @return ImageArticle
     */
    public function setUrl($url)
    {
        $this->url = $url;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get url
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUrl()
    {
        return $this->url;
    }

    /**
     * Set alt
     *
     * @param string $alt
     *
     * @return ImageArticle
     */
    public function setAlt($alt)
    {
        $this->alt = $alt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get alt
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAlt()
    {
        return $this->alt;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function preUpload()
    {
        if (null === $this->file)
        {
            return;
        }


        //On add un extension pour le fichier.
        $this->url = $this->file->guessExtension();
        //Le alt est le nom du fichier du client.
        $this->alt=  $this->file->getClientOriginalName();

    }

    /**
     * 
     * @ORM\PostPersist()
     * @ORM\PostUpdate()
     * 
     */
    public function upload()
    {
        if(null=== $this->file)
        {
            return;
        }

        //Si ancien fichier on supprime
        if(null !== $this->tempFileName)
        {
            $oldFile = $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->id.'.'.$this->tempFileName;
            if (file_exists($oldFile))
            {
                unlink($oldFile);
            }
        }

        //On deplace
        $this->file->move
        (
            $this->getUploadRootDir(),
            $this->id.'.'.$this->url    
        );
    }

    /**
     *@ORM\PreRemove()
     */
    public function preRemoveUpload()
    {
        $this->tempFileName = $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->id.'.'.$this->url;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @ORM\PostRemove()
     */
    public function removeUpload()
    {
        if(file_exists($this->tempFileName))
        {
            unlink($this->tempFileName);
        }
    }
    public function getUploadDir()
    {
        return 'upload/img/';
    }

    protected function getUploadRootDir()
    {
        return __DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getUploadDir().$this->id.'.'.$this->getUrl();
    }

    /**
     * Set source
     *
     * @param string $source
     *
     * @return Image
     */
}
```

I was thinking about a simple foreach loop but it doesn't work...

Comment: Your error is telling you that you try to pass an `array` instead of an item of class `UploadedFile`. Try to remove the `multiple` options from your field, this may render an array instead.

Comment: Thx for your response ! If I remove the multiple option I can't select more than one file.

Comment: Yes I know, but try if you still get the error with only one file. If not your code is correct and i think you should try to make a `foreach` loop in you controller, to save each file alone.

Comment: Oh ok. Yes with only one file it work fine. In my controller I persist/flush my Article. I try to have more than one picture with my article so in ArticleType I call ImageArticleType like this  `->add('imagearticle',          new ImageArticleType(), array('required' => true))`. Can't I make a foreach into my ImageArticle Entity ?

Comment: No, inside your controller, look the answer below

Comment: Hi. I'm sorry but I'm still stuck. Is my answer is correct ?

Answer (score 1):

Uploading files with `multiple` option can be a little bit tricky. With `multiple = false` option your `$file` property in your entity class will return single UploadedFile instance, with `multiple = true` it returns array of UploadedFile instances when you call `$entity->getFile()`. That's why you have to implement the upload process manually, on form submission, in your action, without lifecycle callbacks. Like this:

Action:

```
....
$image = new ImageArticle();

$form = $this->createForm('YOUR_FORM', $image);
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isValid()) {
    ...

    foreach ($image->getFile() as $uploadedFile) {
        $image = new ImageArticle();
        $image
            // setters go here
        ;

        // Upload process go here

        $image->setFile(null);
    }

    $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager')->flush();

    ....
}
```

Here is a screenshot from my project:
[image]

Comment: I've got this error `Type error: Argument 3 passed to Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactory::create() must be of the type array, object given, called in /var/www/html/QrCar/src/AD/PlatformBundle/Controller/CarsController.php on line 296`

Comment: This error is telling you that the `$image` param of your `$this->get('form.factory')->create()` in an object instead of an array. Is your images are save in the `article` entity or another ?

Comment: @Wako `createForm()` method receives `('String formTypeName', Object dataObject, Array options)`, I think you're passing an object as a third parameter. Read [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html)

Answer (score 0):

Something like that ?

```
public function newArticleAction(Request $request)
{
   $article = new Article();
   $article->setUser($this->getUser());

   $imageArticle = new ImageArticle();

   $form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(new \AD\PlatformBundle\Form\ArticleType(), $article, $image); 
    if($form->handleRequest($request)->isValid())
    {
        foreach($imageArticle->getFile() as $imageArticle)
        {
            $imageArticle = new ImageArticle();

            $imageArticle->setAlt($imageArticle->getAlt());
            $imageArticle->setUrl($imageArticle->getUrl());
            $imageArticle->setFile($imageArticle->getFile());

            $imageArticle->preRemoveUpload();
            $imageArticle->preUpload();
            $imageArticle->upload();

        }
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($article);
        $em->flush();

        $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'Article publié ! :)');
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('va_platform_blog'));
    }
    return $this->render('ADPlatformBundle:Cars:newarticle.html.twig', array(
        'form' =>$form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your images are save in the article entity or another (I'll make changes when I get your answer) ?

I have made some little changes to your code. I'm not sure about all the code but I think this should work

```
public function newArticleAction(Request $request)
{
   $article = new Article();
   $images = new ImageArticle();

   $form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(ArticleType::class, $article, $images);
   $form->handleRequest($request);

   if($form->isValid())
   {
       $article->setUser($this->getUser());
       // other article fields, if needed

       foreach($images->getFile() as $image)
       {
           $images->setAlt($image->getAlt());
           $images->setUrl($image->getUrl());
           $images->setFile($image->getFile());

           $images->preRemoveUpload();
           $images->preUpload();
           $images->upload();
       }

       $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
       $em->persist($article);
       $em->flush();

       $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'Article publié ! :)');

       return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('va_platform_blog'));
    }

    return $this->render('ADPlatformBundle:Cars:newarticle.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: I've got two entity : Article.php and ImageArticle.php

Comment: Same error. `Type error: Argument 3 passed to Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactory::create() must be of the type array, object given`

Comment: During the submit or at the page loading ?

Comment: During the page loading

Comment: Can you dump the `$images` in the `$form->isValid()` ? If this do not work comment the foreach

Comment: I can't. If I make a dump before this `$form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(ArticleType::class, $article, $images);` it's ok but if I make it after i've always have the same error.

Comment: After some reseach on Google, they talk about relation between entity. I have `/**
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AD\PlatformBundle\Entity\ImageArticle", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $imagearticle;` in Article.php.

Comment: You are telling your entity that an article can only have one imageArticle and an imageArticle can be in multiple article, is this right ? I think you should inverse your `manyToOne` to `OneToMany`, but I don't think that the error is because of relation (take a look http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html). Because when your are submitting your form it get an object instead an array. You should try to dump/find what is sent to your `$images` param

Comment: Before the foreach $form = ... $images just return my entity ImageArticle object. It's not possible to transform this object in array ?

Comment: Can i give you my Git link ?

Comment: Yep, it will be easier to test imo

Comment: Hi @Jérôme ! Have you a idea about my problem ? :)